# ElementMeshInterpolation and C1 splines

Tags: interpolation, finite-element-method, grid-layouts

I am trying to use `` NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshInterpolation `` on a triangular structured grid constructed from a Delaunay triangulation with zero area triangles dropped.
My question is regarding the kind of spline interpolation being used. I would like at least C^1 accuracy, but none of the options shown seem to have any effect.

> {  {"ExtrapolationHandler" -> Automatic},  {InterpolationOrder ->
>   Automatic},  {Method -> Automatic},  {PeriodicInterpolation -> False}
>   }

Anyone who knows how this works or where this is documented?
Niels

Comment: `InterpolationOrder -> 2` (?)

Answer (score 2):

`InterpolatingFunction` based on triangular unstructured grid uses Lagrange interpolation. Same method is used if `InterpolatingFunction` is created from predefined `ElementMesh` object (with `"MeshOrder"` 1 or 2) by using `ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, values]`.

For interpolation on regular grids of points you can choose between `Method->"Hermite"` or `Method->"Spline"` of arbitrary order. Method `"Spline"` gives you continuous derivatives.